# .htaccess code making a wrong url redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is my `.htaccess` code

```
#RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !hashstar\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

#over here we have set the default root directory now request will be directly made from this directory
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^hashstar.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.hashstar.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !app/
RewriteRule (.*) /app/$1 [L]

#redirect all requests except only POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.(?:php?)[\s?/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

#we are setting here the default file to load while the URL is called followed by fallback files
DirectoryIndex index.php timer/index.php
```

My root directory is set to folder `app`

In app folder, I have 2 folders

```
1.) Manage
2.) Timer
```

To access manage folder I have to type in URL

```
http://www.example.com/manage/
```

To access timer folder I have to type in URL

```
http://www.example.com/timer/
```

if I use these Url by adding a slash in URL `(/)`
the URL loads perfectly

but if the don't add the `(/)` in URL then it makes a redirection through the root directory

URL should look like => `http://www.example.com/manage`

It becomes like => `http://www.example.com/app/manage/`

What's the reason behind it & how to fix this problem?

Any helps appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason of this redirect is that rewritten URI is a real directory without trailing slash. When this happens, Apache's mod_dir module acts on it by redirecting to a URI with a trailing slash.

To prevent use this .htaccess:

```
#we are setting here the default file to load while the URL is called followed by fallback files
DirectoryIndex index.php

#RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !hashstar\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

#redirect all requests except only POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.(?:php?)[\s?/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=301,L,NE]

# adds a trailing directory if rewritten URI is a direcory
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/app/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L]

#over here we have set the default root directory now request will be directly made from this directory
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?hashstar.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/app/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /app/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: this code works fine, but the document root is not set to folder app/ when the src files are provided it starts looking from the public_html folder and not from the public_html/app/ folder which makes the contents to load in appropriate @anubhava :(

Comment: Really sorry @anubhava, your code worked perfectly for me. Actually, I didn't clear my browser cache and data, that's the reason I was getting the same URL. After I cleared my browser data and cache the code worked super duper perfect for me.

Answer (score 1):

At a glance (I didn't try to reproduce these rules in my Apache2 server), it would seem that this is the culprit:

```
RewriteRule (.*) /app/$1 [L]
```

the Regular Expression `(.*)` will catch `Any character greedily`.  Your Rewrite Rule is simply adding `/app/` between the domain and the script.

```
Find and group <all non-null characters>,
    and transform it to /app/<all non-null characters>
```

The URL `www.example.com/myscript.php` would be rewritten as `www.example.com/app/myscript.php`

**EDIT**

> so what code edit do u suggest? @SsJVasto

You could simply exclude `/` from the greedy rule:

```
RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [L]
```

This way, you are storing the result of `anything ending with a /, but without said /` into `$1`.  Since the / isn't inside the group, it will be forgotten.

If you want to handle repetition (like `http://www.example.com/myscript.php//`), you can add a `+` sign to handle `one or more occurrences`:

```
RewriteRule (.*)/+ $1 [L]
```